# Test command inside git bisect run script doesn't work

Tags: bash, git, subshell, git-bisect

I'm using git bisect to find out a version in which the VERSION file has changed from 0.0.1_testing to newer version and I want to use `bisect run` like this.

`git bisect run sh -c 'if [ "$(cat VERSION)" == "0.0.1_testing" ] ; then exit 0 ; else exit 1 ; fi'`

But I keep getting bad result and this error `sh: 1: [: 0.1.0: unexpected operator` (0.1.0 is 
returned by `"$(cat VERSION)"`. I assume that this is because when the subshell exits, bisect uses its exit value and doesn't even go through rest of the script.

Is there a way how to make this work? Or some good alternative? I know I could use other tools than bisect, but I'd really like to do it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were using `bash` you would be able to use either an `=` or `==` for your string comparison, so one solution to your problem is to change `sh` to `bash` in your command.  This is because, for `bash` the `test` command (`[ ... ]` in your command) is a builtin command that supports both comparisons.

The shell you are using does not have the same builtin command and is using the system `test` command which only has `=` as the string comparison.  So, an alternative solution to your problem is to change the `==` to `=` in your command.

Comment: Thank you, this is the solution. So my assumption about the cause of the problem was wrong.